# modified elf symbol but not reflecting in disassembly

Tags: elf

I have used a symbol "__copy_start" inside my assembly code which is coming from linker script. symbol is defined as ABS in symbol table.
This symbol is used inside a macro to copy data from one memory location to another.
After looking at varenter code hereious ways to modify this symbol directly in elf i decided to write C code of my own to modify the symbol value.
To do that i traversed entire symbol table and did string match for the symbol i am interested in. When there is a symbol name match i just assigned symbol_table.st_value = new value.
To make sure the new value is taken i did readelf -s  and checked that it does show the new value assigned by me.

Now, when i disassemble the modified elf i find that the new value has not taken effect and i still see the assembly code doing copy from old symbol value.

My question is:
Am i doing something wrong here? is it possible to change the symbol values in elf? If yes, please let me know the correct way to do it. How do i achieve what i intend to do here.

Note: I don't have the source code so taking this approach.

Thanks in advance,
Gaurav

wanted to add more information so that people can understand better.
copying the elf header below:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  **Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)**
  Machine:                           Ubicom32 32-bit microcontrollers
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xb0000000
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          33548 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x6
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 3
```

Here as you can see that file is of type executable.
output of readelf -S copied below:
There are 6 section headers, starting at offset 0x830c:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        3ffc0000 004000 000ebc 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .sdram            PROGBITS        50000000 008000 0002e4 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0082e4 000028 00      0   0  1
  [ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0083fc 0001c0 10      5  20  4
  [ 5] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0085bc 00019a 00      0   0  1
```

I am using one of the symbol named "__copy_start" in an instruction to copy the data from .sdram section to .text section. I was under an impression that i could go and change the symbol_table.st_value and then get the desired work done. But unfortunately that is not the case. Seems like it is already compiled and cannot be changed like this.
Any idea how this could be done would be really helpful.

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the object code actually uses a relocation to reference the data at the `__copy_start` symbol?  Even for position-independent code, it is usually possible to turn section start addresses into relative addresses, which do not need a relocation.  (That the symbol itself remains present with an absolute address does not change this.)

You can check this by using `readelf -r` or `eu-readelf -r` and examining the output.  It is also visible in the `objdump --dissassemble --reloc` output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually the section is not a relocatable section and symbol table is not dynamic.